# Get Lua Table Entry Using For Loop

Tags: for-loop, lua

I made a table and game script using Lua. The concept as follows:
Start with user guess a displaying random word get from the table (first index), If the user answer is correct then displaying the next random word (next table entry) and so on till all table entries displayed.

How to make it loop using for..do in Lua?.

My current code:

```
WordTable = {
  {lv = 1, v_random = "LEOHL", v_word = "HELLO"},
  {lv = 1, v_random = "GEEINN", v_word = "ENGINE"},
  {lv = 1, v_random = "TECHA", v_word = "CHEAT"},
  {lv = 2, v_random = "dwIl prEARmgorm", v_word = "WILD PROGRAMMER"},
  {lv = 2, v_random = "abDEKory deEPRss", v_word = "KEYBOARD PRESSED"},
 }

function tablelength(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end

function getTypingWord()
 local score = 0
 local point = 0
 index = 1
 count = tablelength(WordTable)
 tab = WordTable[index]

 for index=1,count do
 local rdmWord = tab.v_random
 local crtWord = tab.v_word
 labelWrd.Caption = rdmWord

 local mcWord = string.upper(edtWrd.Text)
 -- edtWrd is a text box

 if mcWord == '' or mcWord == nil then return nil end

 if mcWord == crtWord then
  showMessage('Great, the answer is '..crtWord)
  edtWrd.Text = ''
  point = point+1
  score = point*200
  labelLevel.Caption = 'True : '..point  -- a label
  labelScore.Caption = 'Score : '..score -- a label
  index = index + 1
  tab = WordTable[index]
 else
  showMessage('Try Again')
  edtWrd.Text = ''
 end
 end
end

-- wait user answer till ENTER key has pressed
edtWrd.OnKeyPress = function(sender, key)
if isKeyPressed(VK_RETURN) then getTypingWord() end
 return key
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for a real random loop, or just iterating one by one?
So `for i = 1, #WordTable do` is maybe what you need. Watch [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html).

Comment: @csaar: I need iterating one by one with conditional depending on user input, Example: 1st index of WordTable is "LEOHL", user need to guess what is the correct word, in this case, is "HELLO". So, when user typing "HELLO" on a provided textbox and PRESS ENTER KEY, WordTable index will go next index (next word) and so on until all words have displayed. It's doesn't matter if the user guesses the wrong word, I have a counter timer to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: with this example below

```
 data = {
        {id = 'ronald', say = 'reagan'},
        {id = 'tom', say = 'hank'},
        {id = 'angelina', say = 'jolie'}
        }

 function tablelength(T)
   local count = 0
   for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
   return count
 end

 count = tablelength(data)
 i = 1
 edt = UDF1.CEEdit1  -- edt is the name of textbox

 function CEEdit1KeyPress(sender, key)
  answer = data[i]
  v_word = answer.id..' '..answer.say
  tipo = string.lower(UDF1.CEEdit1.Text)

  if tipo == "" and isKeyPressed(VK_RETURN)== true then return nil end

  if tipo ~= v_word then
   if isKeyPressed(VK_RETURN) == true then
   showMessage('Try again..')
   edt.Text = ''
  end
  elseif tipo == v_word then
   if isKeyPressed(VK_RETURN) == true then
   showMessage('OK. Then answer is : '..v_word)
   edt.Text = ''
   i = i+1
    if i > count then showMessage('All words have displayed') end
  end
 end
 return key
end

UDF1.show()  --Show Form
```

Comment: Hmm, so you are looping with `CEEdit1KeyPress`? Firstly you don't need to define your own tablelength function, because its an array (numeric key). So you can use `#data` or `table.getn(data)` instead of that. Futhermore your loop will fail, if the user doesn't guess the word correct.

Comment: @csaar - Okay, I have correct my script by using #data to get the table.length, Thank's for support,